# data attribute for slick slider

Tags: slider, slick.js

how to make multiple slick-sliders with one function ? For example data attribute;

```
div class="my-slick" data-item="3"

div class="my-slick" data-item="4"

div class="my-slick" data-item="6"

$('.my-slick').slick();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully the following code will work for you

```
<code>
$('.my-slick').each( function() {
 var slick = $(this),
  item =  $(this).data('item');

 slick.slick({
  slidesToShow: item,
  responsive: [
     {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
         slidesToShow: item < 2 ? item: 1,
       }
     }
   ]
 });
});
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

In slick 1.5 you can now add settings using the data-slick attribute. You still need to call $(element).slick() to initialize slick on the element.

```
<div data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 4}'>
  <div><h3>1</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2</h3></div>
  <div><h3>3</h3></div>
  <div><h3>4</h3></div>
  <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  <div><h3>6</h3></div>
</div>
```

You can find more information at http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ and https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/tree/master/slick